# MS Windows Tramp Remote Shell

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, tramp

I'm trying to open a remote shell after connecting to a machine using Tramp with the plink method on MS Windows.

However every time I call `shell` it prompts me for 'Remote shell path' and suggests a local directory.  I think I have to type `/plink:Server:/bin/bash` to be able to run the shell.

Is there any way to avoid having to do this every time I want to run `shell` on a remote machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `explicit-shell-file-name` for this:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")
```

The disadvantage is, that this setting is valid for all shell buffers you open, local and remote ones. In the upcoming Emacs 26, there is support for connection-local variables. This will give you the ability to set `explicit-shell-file-name` for different remote machines with a different value.